# Maven Compiler Plugin Failure Local Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I have a project (tester) that depends on another project (client). I've made changes to "client" project and linked "tester" project using the java build path. Eclipse recognizes the link and the changes I made in "client" project and wants me to correct files in the "tester" project. I make the changes, but when I try to build the maven-compiler-plugin (3.6.1) complains about the changes to the "tester" project and fails to compile.

Summary:
I added a new method to an implementation in project "client"
I linked the Java Build path in project "tester"
Eclipse recognizes the new method and wants me to add it to project "tester"
Maven-compiler-plugin complains that the new method is not allowed (Error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype)

I did notice that the new version of the "client" project is 1.2 but the dependencies still list 0.2, but updating or cleaning or setting the pom.xml does not change it to the new version.

Any idea what I can do to make the compiler plugin use the new (local) build version? Or am I missing some other setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the version to a what it would be in the repository, 0.2.{DATE} (ex: 0.2.20170805999999) and then "mvn install" and update the dependent project. Now it compiled with the correct version of the jar.

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project > properties >java compiler > select the desired version and click on apply then ok. Update your project by right click on your project > maven > update Maven.

Comment: the version was in reference to the "client" project where I added a method to the interface, not the java compiler version